# Show posts from particular category first then remaining wpQuery

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to show the posts  from particular category and after that all remaining posts from other  remaining category.
this is my query. what changes to done in `$args` array for achieving my goal. 
**note that i can only use one loop.**

**this is my query.**

```
$args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'event',
            'meta_key'          =>  '_event_end_date',  
            'meta_compare'      => '>',
            'meta_value'        => $today, 
            'order'             =>  'DESC',
            'orderby'           =>'category',
            'paged'             =>$paged1,
        );
```

Comment: I think have to execute two query one for your particular category and another one for Remaining.

Comment: no that cant be done.some restriction.  any order by category ...or something can be done?